# Routing, hitting wrong action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have two actions, and whenever I explicitly call the second one, the first one still gets called. I need to be able to write in mysite.com/api/Awesome/GetSomeExamples, without it always triggering GetAllClasses

```
public class AwesomeController : Controller
{
   public IEnumerable<myClass> GetAllClasses()
   {
      //...some stuff
   }
   public IEnumerable<string> GetSomeExamples()
   {
       //...some stuff
   }
     //... also have some more actions which take in one parameter
}
```

my routing is as such, but not working

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Error I am getting: **Multiple actions were found that match the request**

Comment: The routes you have specified are correct. You are probably calling the method internally from one method to the other. Please check the code inside GetSomeExamples.

Comment: I did have it called in javascript but only on a certain page, I removed (just incase) but I am still getting this error:

Multiple actions were found that match the request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Web API.

The difference with normal MVC actions is that Web API looks at the HTTP verb to determine the action to call. In this case you have two methods that start with `Get`

However, this should trigger an error: `Multiple actions were found that match the request...`
and it shouldn't call both actions.

The URL you need is:

```
mysite.com/api/Awesome/
```

From there, Web API will call a method that starts with `Get`. You need to remove the other get method and put it in a different controller. Web API supposes you have one action per http verb

Comment: Thanks, never knew Web API acted differently, thanks. Sucks that I have to put the action in another controller, as they are both getting similar data. One is getting all of the data, while the other is getting all the data that is different.